# Show $ax+b=0$ has only one solution

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory

Given K a field, and $a,b \in K, a\ne0$, show $ax+b=0$ has only one solution.

is it possible to just say $ax=-b \rightarrow x=a^{-1}*-b$, we can multiply by $a^{-1}$ because each element has inverse.

Does this prove the linear equation has only one solution?

Comment: it seems correct to me, once it is an equivalence.

Comment: Yes, you proved that any solution must equal $-a^{-1}b$ (beware the order). Moreover, it is clear that this is indeed a solution.

Comment: (Actually nevermind the order, a field is commutative by definition)

Answer (score 0):

That's ok; but you only used one-directional implication, sp now you need to go back and check that that is a solution indeed. Without checking, what you showed is that"If the equation has a solution, then it is $-b a^{-1}$. So it's possible it has that solution, and it's also possible it has no solutions, if you don't check that that's always a solution.

Alternatively you could just replace the one-directional arrow by a bi-directional arrow and you're done.

Comment: Does the terminology "field" implies commutativity, actually? Shouldn't it rather be $-a^{-1}b$?

Comment: @Suzet Fields are commutative yes. The definition of a field is a commutative ring with identity in which every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse. And since zero divisors can't be multiplicative inverses (units), a field also automatically has no zero divisors.

Comment: I see, got it! It's good to know. French terminology is somewhat different, the translation we use for "field" (that is corps) does not usually imply commutativity actually. That is why I got confused.

Comment: @Suzet So "corps" is what we call in English "field"? Or "corps" is what field translates to in French, but "corps" is not commutative?

Comment: The latter. "Corps" is a ring with identity in which every non-zero element is invertible. Actually, I guess this is a division ring in English. However, we mainly and most commonly think of the term "field" when translating it to English, which may cause confusion in some cases - I realize it now. If I want to consider a field, I should say "corps commutatif" instead of just "corps", from now on.

Comment: @Suzet Ah ok got it.

Comment: @Suzet. Does French math use the French word "champ"?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No, it has no meaning whatsoever in mathematics (even though it is literally the translation of field : a corn field is "un champ de maïs" in French). In maths, it's just different. "Corps" actually means body.

Comment: @Suzet,,,,50 years ago I heard that the terminology in Russian was the same type as  what you have described for French. I don't know whether that is still the case. And, as I am Canadian, it occurs to me to wonder what the usage is in Quebec.... BTW a Facebook group that I just joined  (Cute Kittens) says "This is an international group so use English"... Ugh. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use $\iff$ as much as possible in proofs you will more likely avoid the mistake of only proving half of what is needed.  For example:

If $a\ne 0$ then $a^{-1}$ exists;  therefore $$ax+b=0\iff a^{-1}(ax+b)=a^{-1}0=0 \iff$$ $$\iff x+a^{-1}b=0\iff$$ $$\iff (x+a^{-1}b )+(-a^{-1}b)=0+(-a^{-1}b)=-a^{-1}b\iff$$ $$\iff x=-a^{-1}b.$$ BTW. The justification for the first "$\iff$" , above, is that $$ax+b=0\implies a^{-1}(ax+b)=a^{-1}(0)\implies$$ $$\implies a(a^{-1}(ax+b))=a(a^{-1})(0)\implies$$ $$\implies (a\cdot a^{-1})(ax+b)=(a\cdot a^{-1})(0)\implies$$ $$\implies (1)(ax+b)=(1)(0)\implies$$ $$\implies ax+b=0.$$ That is , when you  have a string such  as $A\implies B\implies C\implies D \implies A,$ then you have $A\iff B.$

Comment: The basic rules of arithmetic apply verbatim in any field. Just be careful when attempting to divide by an integer  because in a field you can have $1+1=0.$  And  a linear order  $< ,$ such that $<$ has some   useful relation to $+$ and $\times ,$ might not exist.